# How to make Kotlin lambda to work in generics class

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I am converting my [signals](https://github.com/gazman-sdk/Life-Cycle) library from Java to Kotlin, and I am having trouble making Kotlin play nice with lambda expressions.

This is how the library looks like:

```
object Signals{

   fun <T : Any> inject(type: KClass<T>): Signal<T> {
      
   }
}

class Signal<T : Any>{
      fun addListener(listener: T){
      }
}
```

Now I want to inject the TestMe interface.

```
interface TestMe{
    fun onTest(message:String)
}

@Test
fun inject() {
    val testMeSignal = Signals.inject(TestMe::class)
    testMeSignal.addListener(...)     
}
```

I want it to use lambda as fallow:

```
    testMeSignal.addListener({s:String-> println(s)})
```

But the only thing that works is

```
    testMeSignal.addListener(object: TestMe{
        override fun onTest(s: String) {
            println(s)
        }
    })
```

How do I make lambda work here?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html

Answer (score 1):

To be able to use SAM conversion, you can declare `TestMe` as a [fun interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html):

```
fun interface TestMe{
    fun onTest(message:String)
}
```

And then you can use:

```
testMeSignal.addListener { s: String ->
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that is working as intended.

Your `addListener` expects an instance of a class that implements `TestMe`. So you need to create an object extending `TestMe` implementing all the functions needed.

If you were to pass a lambda as a param it will not be an implementation of your class.

Not sure what you intend to do, but maybe you want to have a function where you define the type of lambda expected?

```
fun myFun(f: (String) -> Unit)
```

In your case the `object: TestMe` looks the correct solution.